# How to iterate through different objects with only one object info node in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have an OBJ sequence exported from Houdini. I have imported the entire sequence into blender, with each object being one frame. I want to make a separate object with a geometry node tree that imports the correct object in the sequence for each frame, so that it iterates through the list as the frame number increases. I could do this with an object info node for each one, and a lot of switch nodes, but that would take forever to set up and could not be used on other sequences.
I am aware of the stop motion OBJ addon; the reason I am doing it this way is so I can copy the vertex positions onto the geometry of the first frame so that it is no longer a sequence but an animated mesh ( I think that is how it works?)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put them all in collections, and use a `Collection Info` instead. The exact method would depend on your project, but you can instantiate, delete or otherwise manipulate them after that, by matching their indices with `Scene Time`—*Frame*. Here are two example setups:

[image]

[image]

[image]